# Does the word 有不好的預感 mean いやなよかんがする in Japanese?

Tags: meaning, translation

I also asked [the same question in HiNative](https://hinative.com/questions/24549939).

Comment: It's a Chinese phrase, not Japanese.

Comment: This made me cringe

Answer (score 2):

No, the word 有不好的預感 is not a word in Japanese.

If you are asking whether 不好的預感 (whatever this language is) means いやなよかんがする in Japanese, then you should know [this site is not a proofreading/translation service](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799), so you'd better ask somewhere else or look it up in a dictionary.

You don't need to keep making duplicate questions in both HiNative and Japanese Stackexchange. Even though both sites help you with Japanese, their goals and usage are different.